# Cropping out files from a list of files in bash

Tags: bash, shell

So I would like to do a simple find in a dir with:

```
find /HOME/ | grep .properties
```

Then with this list I want to weed out certain files, lets say one is server.properties and another is testing.properties.

After those have been taken out, I want to do a quick for loop that will pass each remaning file that didn't get filtered out into a function one by one. The function call is just something like

```
extractHash FILE OUTPUTFILE
```

I hope this makes sense, I'll try to be more clear if it's not.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for file in "`find ~ -name \*.properties |grep -v -e server.properties -e testfile.properties`"; do
    extractHash $file output
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `while`, not `for`, for iterating over files: `for` will not work as you expect for iterating over the output of a backtick-ed program if there is extraneous whitespace:

```
find /HOME -name \*.properties \! -name server.propertiees \! -name testing.properties` |
while read -r file; do
    extractHash "$file" OUTPUTFILE
done
```

If all your files are in the current directory, use an extended globbing pattern, and `for` is appropriate to iterate over filename wildcards:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in !(server|testing).properties; do
  extractHash "$file" out
done
```

Comment: Technically, it's bad to use `find | while`, it's better to use `find -print0 | xargs -0`.

Comment: @GreyCat, why would you say that? What if you don't have GNU find and xargs (for the -print0/-0 options)? I realize that the while loop is in a subshell, so variables won't survive. What other reasons do you have for saying "technically it's bad"?

Comment: Rationale: 1. Bash's read would break on filenames that contain "\n". 2. Yeah, it's subshell with all pros and cons of a subshell: i.e. speed issues, variable isolation, somewhat non-intuitive exit status handling, etc. 3. `xargs` solution offers major speed improvement options, such as `-n` (processing several lines of input, i.e. several files with one invocation of command) and `-P` (run several instances of processing command in parallel). The only downside that I see is, yeah, that it involves using GNU tools, but if you're using `find`, it's hard to stay portable anyway.

Comment: +1 on avoiding `find | while read`... if the innards of the loop reads input, you'll need to do funky things w/ renaming input/output:  e.g.:  `printf "a \n b \n c \n d \n" | while read -r x; do echo "==run script on $x"; read -p "need more info: " input;  echo "what? input=$input"; done` => the "read" in the loop starts consuming the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

In csh you would use foreach:

```
#!/bin/csh 
set files=`find /HOME/ | grep .properties`

foreach file ($files)
  set outfile = $file.out
  extractHash $file $outfile
end
```

not sure about bash - it has a similar for loop but I never learned it :)

Comment: [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend using the `-name` argument for `find` instead of piping every filename through `grep`.  Then you can do something like:

```
for file in `find /HOME -name \*.properties \! -name server.propertiees \! -name testing.properties`; do
    extractHash "$file" OUTPUTFILE
done
```